# Algoritmo para ordenação de vetores

Tags: algoritmo

Bom dia. A minha dúvida está na linha 9. O correto seria:

```
para j de i + 1 até 3 passo 1 faça
```

ou

```
para j de i + 1 até 3 faça
```

Segue o algoritmo completo:

```
Algoritmo numero_crescente
      var vet: vetor[1..3] de inteiro
          i,j,aux:inteiro
Inicio
      para i de 1 até 3 passo 1 faça
            Escreva("Digite um numero")
            Leia(vet[i])
      Fim-para
      para i de 1 até 2 passo 1 faça
          para j de i + 1 até 3 passo 1 faça
              se vet[i] > vet[j] entao
                aux <- vet[j]
                vet[j] <- vet[i]
                vet[i] <- aux
               Fim-se
          Fim-para
      Fim-para
      para i de 1 até 3 passo 1 faça
          Escreva(vet[i])
      Fim-para   
Fim
```

Comment: outra duvida nessa sequencia eu estou fazendo o J valer 2 e no loop ele valer 3 ?

 para i de 1 até 2 passo 1 faça
          para j de i + 1 até 3 passo 1 faça

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tanto faz. Quando você não põe o valor do passo, subentende-se que tal valor é 1.

O algoritmo que você implementa é uma variante do [selection sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). No entanto, para que você possa vislumbrar melhor o seu comportamento, sugiro que use um vetor com mais do que 3 elementos apenas.

Comment: vlw, consegue me informar se tem algum erro nesse algoritmo ?

Comment: @RafaelLopes Resposta editada.